# The most efficient way to find mode in an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, mode

Recently I am trying to find the mode in a set of number by using C.
My code can done well when the set is small.

Here is my code:

```
int frequency[10001]; //This array stores the frequency of a number that between 0 to 10000
int main()
{
    int x[10]={1,6,5,99,1,12,50,50,244,50};
    int highest = 0;
    int i,j,k;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        frequency[x[i]]++;
        if(frequency[x[i]]>highest)
            highest = frequency[x[i]];
    }

    printf("The mode in the array : ");
    for(i=0;i<=10001;i++)
        if(frequency[i]==highest)
            printf("%d ",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Later, I found out that my method will be extremely slow if there is a large set of number. Also, my program will not work if there is number smaller than 0 or greater than 10000, unless I increase the size of the "frequency" array.

Therefore, I would like to know is there any way that I can find the mode in the array more efficiently? Thanks.

Comment: careful: `for(i=0;i<=10001;i++)` => `for(i=0;i<10001;i++)`

Comment: I will give you a hint, get maximum number in array, then define the array like this frequency[max_number]

Comment: why not when you store `highest` also store the `index` of where the `highest` is it will save you the second pass. Combine this with the hint given above to find the maximum. Could use an unordered_map with the `save the highest` strategy as well.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: follow below link for answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920542/c-calculating-the-mode-of-a-sorted-array/55983460#55983460

Answer (score 3):

Use a [hash table](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/tutorial/).  (i.e. unordered_map is typically implemented as such).

You tagged your question as C++, so you're going to get some sample code in C++.  Your on your own for implementing a hash table in C.  It's not a bad learning exercise.

```
int x[10]={1,6,5,99,1,12,50,50,244,50};
std::unordered_map<int, int> table; // map of items in "x" to the number of times observed.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     table[x[i]]++;
}

int mode = 0;
int mode_freq = 0;
for (auto itor = table.begin(); itor != table.end(); itor++)
{
    if (itor->second > mode_freq)
    {
        mode = itor->first;
        mode_freq = itor->second;
    }
}
std::cout << "The mode in the array is " << mode << std::endl;
```

Comment: How do we know how many items `std::unordered_map` allocates per default? Or will the `[]` operator allocate new ones? Seems strange, STL doesn't usually behave like that. You sure this isn't a bug?

Comment: @Lundin `operator[]` default constructs an element to return when passed a new key. Only `map` and `unordered_map` have `operator[](key_type)`, and they both behave this way

Comment: @Lundin that is the reason if you a pass user defined object to the `unordered_map` as value and you do not have a default ctor the compiler will complain.

Comment: @Lundin: `op[]` will create elements, just as it always has with a map in C++ (since 20 years ago and in the STL before that).

Comment: That being said, despite mistagging, the OP said "using C", and C doesn't have `std::unordered_map` (or any of the other C++isms displayed in this answer). Hopefully they will settle on a language and let us know.

Comment: Ok so my C++ is rusty but I'm pretty sure std::vector would crash and burn if you feed it the very same code. So the various STL containers behave inconsistently then?

Comment: You can replace the second loop with `std::max_element` and a custom compare, `auto mode_it = std::max_element(table.begin(), table.end(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs.second < rhs.second; });`, but all this is only applicable if OP wants a C++ answer

Comment: @Lundin The sequence containers behave differently to the associative containers, yes

Comment: It is ok to have C++ answer, although I am still new to it

Comment: @Caleth Lovely consistent language. They probably didn't name it hash table because the committee had already used up all hash...

Comment: @Lundin There is `std::hash<T>`, calculates the hash for a key (:

Comment: @Lundin it's named `unordered_map` for it's *behaviour*, rather than `hash_map` for it's *implementation*. In much the same way it is `map`, and not `red_black_tree_map` (or w/e)

Comment: @Caleth Too bad all computer science classes teaches about hash tables then, and not "unordered maps"... The real question here is if we should name them std::unordered_committee or std::hash_committee. Gah, who lured me into a C++ discussion!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply sort your array (man qsort), and then search for the longuest sequence of the same number.
The question is : how do you behave when two number equally appear at the most frequency in the array ?

Comment: It is indeed the *standard* way in statistical analysis to find modes, median value and percentiles...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is too general to get a definite answer:

- the "most efficient" is a pretty big requirement, I guess you would be interested in any "more" efficient solution :).
- more efficient in what way? Faster execution time? Less memory usage? Better code?

First of all I would have written this little piece like this:

```
static const size_t NUM_FREQ=1000;

int main()
{
    vector< unsigned int > frequency(NUM_FREQ);
    vector< unsigned int > samples[10]={1,6,5,99,1,12,50,50,244,50};
    int highest = 0;
    int i,j,k;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < samples.size(); i++ )
    {
    assert( samples[i] < NUM_FREQ && "value in samples is bigger than expected" ); 
        frequency[ samples[ i ] ]++;
        if( frequency[ samples[ i ] ] > highest )
            highest = frequency[ samples[ i ] ];
    }

    printf("The mode in the array : ");
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < frequency.size(); i++ )
        if ( frequency[ i ] == highest )
            printf("%d ",i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Out of all the bad practices that I changed, the one you should be more careful with is relying on plain types implicit initialization.

Now, there are a number of things that may or may not be wrong with this:

- The most obvious is that you do not need to loop over it twice, just use an extra variable to remember the location of the highest frequency and get rid of the second loop completely.
- In your example, there are very few samples and using such a big frequency array is a waste of space. If the size of samples is less than the NUM_FREQ I would simply use a vector of pairs. I assume that your real application uses a sample array that is bigger than the frequency array.
- Finally sorting or hashing could accelerate things but it very much depends on how the frequency data is used in the rest of your application (but you haven't shown anything but this simple code).

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot find an occurrence of a **negative** number.You can only find the occurrence of a number.
- Instead of using an array of `frequency[10001]` use [MAPS in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/).

---

Now let me modify your code.By using maps instead of arrays.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int x[10]={1,6,5,99,1,12,50,50,244,50};
  map <int, int> freq;//using map here instead of frequency array
  int highiest=0;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    freq[x[i]]+=1;//indexing
  }
  for(int i=0;i<sizeof(freq);i++)
  {
    if(freq[i]>highiest)//finding the highiest occurancy of a number.
    highiest=i;
  }
  cout<<highiest<<endl;//printing the highiest occurancy number
}
```