# How to fix a segmentation fault: 11 in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, unix, visual-studio-code, g++

I am currently working on a program that takes the mode from an array of numbers using a template function. The code will compile with no problems using g++ on my macOS (i.e. no errors, warnings, etc.). However when I run the code I get this output in the terminal:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T>
T mode(const T* values, size_t length) {
    if (length < 0) throw std::out_of_range{ 0 };
    T result{};
    int number = values[0];
    int count = 1; 
    int countMode = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == number) {
            countMode++;
        }
        else {
            if (count > countMode) {
                countMode = count;
                result = number;
            }
            count = 1;
            number = values[i];
         }
    }

    if (sizeof(result) > 1) throw std::range_error{ 0 };
    else {
        return result;
    }
 }

int main() {
   const int arr[] = { 1, 4, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6 };
   int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
   const auto result = mode<int>(arr, arr_size);
   printf("Mode = %d\n", result);
}
```

I got part of my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920690/10942068)

The expected output is this:

```
"Mode = 1"
```

Comment: `length < 0` will never be true because `length` is an unsigned type.  What is `if (sizeof(result) > 1)` supposed to be checking on?  This will always be true.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and it will tell you where the segmentation fault occurred. Then add this information to your question if you do not understand why it occurs at that place.

Comment: what is the version of the compiler you are using here?

Comment: *The code will compile with no problems* -- Having a program compile ok only means that the program has no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the program has logic errors or not.  If programs compiling ok were the only requirement for programs to work correctly, there would be no such thing as bugs.  Also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: what is you want to accomplish? e.g. `int number = values[0]` not T ? is something special supposed to be in the first position of the array?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I guess if T is char it will not be true, not that I understand why he needs the check

Comment: While your program logic is flawed as already mentioned by others, I couldn't find any clear reason for this to cause a segmentation fault, so I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924295/construct-standard-exceptions-with-null-pointer-argument) whether the condensed example of the segmentation fault causing part of your program is actually allowed to cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

I got that error (not a segmentation fault)

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

So

```
 if (sizeof(result) > 1) throw std::range_error{ 0 };
    else {
        return result;
    }
 }
```

is what causes the problem because `sizeof(result)` returns 4 for `int result`, hence the exception is thrown and there is no catcher.

Comment: That should not cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @walnut seems we have different compilers, then

Comment: In any case OP claims to observe a segmentation fault, not a call to terminate/abort.

Comment: I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924295/construct-standard-exceptions-with-null-pointer-argument-and-impossible-postcond) to clarify it, but as I mentioned in my previous (now deleted) comment,  throwing the `range_error` exception itself should not cause a segmentation fault or the particular terminate message you are seeing. The problem is that OP is passing a null pointer constant to the constructor of the exception which most likely causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I just added your edit to my code and it got ride of the segmentation fault. However, I am now got "Mode = 0" instead of "Mode = 1".

Comment: @wtsegars This is another question. So post a new question.