# Construct standard exceptions with null pointer argument and impossible postconditions

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
#include<stdexcept>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::range_error(nullptr);
    } catch(const std::range_error&) {
        std::cout << "Caught!\n";
    }
}
```

GCC and Clang with libstdc++ call `std::terminate` and abort the program with the message

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

Clang with libc++ segfaults on construction of the exception.

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7uzyZX).

Are the compilers behaving standard-conform? The relevant section of the standard [[diagnostics.range.error]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/diagnostics#range.error) (C++17 N4659) does say that `std::range_error` has a `const char*` constructor overload which should be preferred over the `const std::string&` overload. The section also does not state any preconditions on the constructor and only states the postcondition

> *Postconditions*: `strcmp(what(), what_­arg) == 0`.

This postcondition always has undefined behavior if `what_arg` is a null pointer, so does this mean that my program also has undefined behavior and that both compilers act conformant? If not, how should one read such impossible postconditions in the standard?

---

On second thought, I think it must mean undefined behavior for my program, because if it didn't then (valid) pointers not pointing to null-terminated strings would also be allowed, which clearly makes no sense.

So, assuming that is true, I would like to focus the question more on how the standard implies this undefined behavior. Does it follow from the impossibility of the postcondition that the call also has undefined behavior or was the precondition simply forgotten?

---

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923969/how-to-fix-a-segmentation-fault-11-in-c).

Comment: It sounds like [std::range_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/range_error) is allowed to store things by reference, so I wouldn't be surprised. Calling `what()` when `nullptr` is passed would probably cause problems.

Comment: @Chipster I am not sure what exactly you mean, but after thinking about this again, I think it must be undefined behavior. I have edited my question to focus it more on *how* the standard wording implies undefined behavior.

Comment: If  `nullptr` is passed, I would think that `what()` would have to dereference it at some point to get the value. That would be dereferencing a `nullptr`, which is problematic at best and certain to crash are worst.

Comment: I agree, though. It must be undefined behavior. However, putting that into an adequate answer explaining why is beyond my skills.

Comment: I think it is intended that it is a precondition that the argument points to a valid C string, since `strcmp` is used to describe the value of `what_arg`.  That's what the relevant [section from the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A809%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D) says anyway, which is referred to by the specification of `<cstring>`. Of course the wording could be clearer.

Comment: One could argue that `range_error` does not specifically allow a `nullptr` as I'd expect if it really was allowed. I'd also expect some description of what it's supposed to do if it gets a `nullptr`. Testing for `nullptr` also has some small cost which I assume also speaks against `nullptr` being allowed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/range_error):

> Because copying std::range_error is not permitted to throw exceptions,
>   this message is typically stored internally as a separately-allocated
>   reference-counted string. This is also why there is no constructor
>   taking std::string&&: it would have to copy the content anyway.

This shows why you get segfault, the api does really treat it as a real string. 
In general in cpp if something was optional, there will be an overloaded constructor/function that does not take what it does not need. So passing `nullptr` for a function that does not document something to be optional is going to be undefined behavior. Usually API's don't take pointers with the exception for C strings. So IMHO it is safe to assume passing nullptr for a function that expects a `const char *`, is going to be undefined behavior. Newer APIs may prefer `std::string_view` for those cases.

Update:

Usually it is fair to assume a C++ API taking a pointer to accept NULL. However C strings are a special case. Until `std::string_view`, there was no better way to pass them efficiently. In general for an API accepting `const char *`, assumption should be is that it has to be a valid C string. i.e a pointer to a sequence of `char`s that terminates with a '\0'.

`range_error` could validate that the pointer is not `nullptr` but it cannot validate if it terminates with a '\0'. So it better not do any validation.

I don't know the exact wording in the standard, but this pre-condition is probably assumed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is undefined behavior. [res.on.arguments] [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.arguments#1.1):

> 1.1 - If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as [...] a pointer invalid for its intended use), the behavior is undefined.

Clearly checking postconditions is an intended use of a function (or constructor) argument.

Is a null pointer invalid here as an argument to `strcmp`?  [cstring.syn] [refers us](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstring.syn#1) to the C library; referring to the appropriate Standard ([specifically C17](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.refs#1.3) according to [intro.refs], not that it makes a difference which version of the C standard we consult), in **7.1.4 Use of library functions** we read:

> 1 - [...] If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as [...] a null pointer [...]) [...] the behavior is undefined.

Then, **7.24.1 String function conventions** says:

> 1 - The header `<string.h>` declares [...] several functions [...] useful for manipulating arrays of character type and other objects treated as arrays of character type. [...] in all cases a `char *` or `void *` argument points to the initial (lowest addressed) character of the array.

And **7.24.4.2 The strcmp function** says:

> 2 - The `strcmp` function compares the string pointed to by `s1` to the string pointed to by `s2`.

And, circling back to **7.1.1 Definitions of terms**, we read:

> 1 - A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. [...] A *pointer to
> a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character.

So a null pointer is an invalid argument to `strcmp`, so checking the postcondition has undefined behavior, so the null pointer is invalid for its intended use as a constructor argument to `std::range_error`, so certainly the program has undefined behavior; both compilers are conformant since anything can happen when undefined behavior is encountered at runtime.

Answer (score -2):

This goes back to the basic question is it OK to create a std::string from nullptr? and what should it do it is?

[www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) says

> If s is a null pointer, if n == npos, or if the range specified by [first,last) is not valid, it causes undefined behavior.

So when

```
throw std::range_error(nullptr);
```

is called the implementation tries to make something like

```
store = std::make_shared<std::string>(nullptr);
```

which is undefined. Which I would consider a bug (without having read the actual wording in the standard). Instead the libery developers could have made something like

```
if (what_arg)
  store = std::make_shared<std::string>(nullptr);
```

But then the catcher has to check for nullptr in `what();` or it will just crash there. So the `std::range_error` should assign either an empty string or "(nullptr)" like some other languages does.

Comment: “This goes back to the basic question is it OK to create a std::string from nullptr?” — I don’t think it does.

Comment: I don't think the standard specifies anywhere that the exception has to save a `std::string` and the `std::string` constructor should not be chosen by overload resolution.

Comment: The `const char *` overload is selected by overload resolution